# Testing Express, MongoDB & TypeScript with supertest and Jest fails when I use app

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, testing, supertest

I want to test my Express, MongoDB, TypeScript REST-Api, but I am having difficulty with a line of code where supertest takes `app` as parameter. The test fails and I get the 404 status code instead of 200.

```
const resVar = await supertest(app).get(`/`);
expect(resVar.statusCode).toBe(200);
```

However when I replace the parameter app with `http://localhost:${EXPRESS_APP_PORT}/api/v1/users` the test passes and I get a 200 status code. 
This is a small project and you can get & clone all the code on this [Github repository](https://github.com/kimanicharles911/express_typescript_rest_api_w_JWT_auth).
Looking forward to your help.

`server.ts` (server initialization location/file) ⬇

```
import express, {Application} from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import {deserializeUserFunc} from './middleware/deserializeUser';
import {routes} from './routes/index';

const initServer = () => {
  const app: Application = express();
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(deserializeUserFunc);
  app.use('/api/v1/users', routes);
  return app;
};

export {initServer}
```

`index.ts` (connection to MonGODB & listening to port occurs here, but not for testing environment.) ⬇

```
import {initServer} from './server';
import {EXPRESS_APP_PORT, MONGO_DB_USERNAME, MONGO_DB_DATABASE} from './config';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
const mongoDbPassword = process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD;
import pinoLogger from './logger';

// connect to online mongoDB
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${MONGO_DB_USERNAME}:${mongoDbPassword}@emmethubclusterone.disfr.mongodb.net/${MONGO_DB_DATABASE}?retryWrites=true&w=majority` )
  .then(() => {
    pinoLogger.info(`Connected to ${MONGO_DB_DATABASE} database.`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    pinoLogger.error(`${err} Error connecting to ${MONGO_DB_DATABASE} database!`);
    process.exit(1);
  })

const app = initServer();

app.listen(EXPRESS_APP_PORT, () => {
  pinoLogger.info(`App server is listening at http://localhost:${EXPRESS_APP_PORT}`);
})
```

`product.test.ts` (my file with the test that fails.) ⬇

```
import supertest from 'supertest';
import {initServer} from "../server" ;
import {MongoMemoryServer} from 'mongodb-memory-server';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const app = initServer();

describe('product', () => {

  beforeAll( async() => {
    const mongoServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
    await mongoose.connect(mongoServer.getUri())
  })

  afterAll(async() => {
    await mongoose.disconnect();
    await mongoose.connection.close();
  })

  describe('get product route', () => {
    describe('given the product exists', () => {
      it('should return a 200 and the product', async() => {
        const resVar = await supertest(app).get(`/`);
        expect(resVar.statusCode).toBe(200);
      })
    });

  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of the route you specified in `product.test.ts`. In `index.ts` you state `app.use('/api/v1/users', routes);` but in `product.test.ts` you target:

```
await supertest(app).get(`/`);
```

Try with

```
await supertest(app).get(`/api/v1/users`);
```

Comment: Thankyou, I believe the issue is not about app.ts and app.listen(). I have changed the filename of app.ts to -> index.ts to remove a confusion that was there. I have also made that change on Github. You can clone and have a look.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think the issue is in the URL that you pass to `supertest(app).get('/');` it should be `supertest(app).get('/api/v1/users');` Let me know if that was it.

Comment: I never knew the promise based http client overlooks routes and only regards the root URL. Thankyou very much @perthos for helping me out. May God bless you.

Comment: Glad to help,! Yes, `supertest` exposes the host and port and then you just specify the endpoint.